# Funeral site auto login / form field auto fill

Tags: html, url, curl, autofill, populate

For a funeral video streaming site, it wants username & password to direct the viewer to the correct service. The username/password are not private so the info can sit in code or a URL without any worry. Many viewers are elderly and entering data is an unnecessary step. Is it possible to create a link/URL (or any other simple thing that can be emailed or posted on a website) so that the viewer can click on, which would open the site, auto-fill the fields and best-case 'press' the log-in button too?

Comment: Probably yes. What you want sounds like login with email links or using 2FA. However, your question is very broad. Narrowing it down would help others give you better answers. [This article might help.](https://blog.medium.com/signing-in-to-medium-by-email-aacc21134fcd)

Comment: Thanks. You've over thought the problem. It is literally a landing page with two fields (Username and Password) and a 'Login' button. I would like to either:
 A. auto-fill the fields, or
 B. autofill the fields and 'press' the log-in button.

A URL 'push' doesn't work (eg "www.site.com/?Username=abc&Password=123")